# Have created a docker that installs nginx, python, uwsgi and django. How do I test it within a VM?

Tags: django, nginx, docker, uwsgi

I have created the [following project](https://github.com/simkimsia/aws-docker-django/blob/master/Dockerfile) using docker.

Here is the Dockerfile

```
############################################################
# Purpose   : Dockerize Django App to be used in AWS EC2
# Django    : 1.8.1
# OS        : Ubuntu 14.04
# WebServer : nginx
# Database  : Postgres inside RDS
# Python    : 2.7
# VERSION   : 0.1
############################################################

from ubuntu:14.04

maintainer Kim Stacks, kimcity@gmail.com

# make sure package repository is up to date
# this is commented out because it clashes with install build-essential
# run echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe" > /etc/apt/sources.list

run apt-get update

# run apt-get upgrade --force-yes -y

# install python
run apt-get install python  --force-yes -y              ## install 2.7
run apt-get install python-setuptools --force-yes -y    ## for python2.7 or above
run apt-get install build-essential --force-yes -y      ##
run apt-get install python-virtualenv --force-yes -y    ## virtual env
run apt-get install python-dev --force-yes -y       ## because ubuntu 14.04 does not have dev version of python 2


# install nginx
run apt-get install \
        nginx \
        --force-yes -y

## copy the nginx config files
COPY ./nginx_configuration/common.conf      /etc/nginx/common.conf
COPY ./nginx_configuration/fastcgi_params   /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
COPY ./nginx_configuration/nginx.conf       /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./nginx_configuration/php.conf         /etc/nginx/php.conf
COPY ./nginx_configuration/default          /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
COPY ./nginx_configuration/php.example      /etc/nginx/sites-available/php.example
COPY ./nginx_configuration/django-app.conf      /etc/nginx/sites-available/django-app.conf

## copy the bash_rc over
# COPY ./bash_files/.bash_profile           /root/.bash_profile

run /etc/init.d/nginx restart


########################################
## Install Django 
## and associated python modules
########################################

# Install pip
RUN easy_install pip

# Add and install Python modules
ADD requirements.txt /src/requirements.txt
RUN cd /src; pip install -r requirements.txt


# Bundle app source
ADD ./djangoapp /src

########################################
## Remove any unwanted packages
########################################
run apt-get autoremove --force-yes -y
```

I have a VM that is Ubuntu14.04, so I ran the docker **inside** the guest OS.

```
docker build -t django18-python27-ubuntu1404 . ## build docker reponame dockerfilepath

docker run -ti django18-python27-ubuntu1404 sh ## run the docker and go in
```

Once I am **inside** the docker, I go to `/src` and then run `uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini`

**My question is how do I test the djangoapp inside `/src` of the docker container?**

My host OS is Mac OS X Mavericks.

My guest OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

My docker is run **inside** the guest OS.

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your docker file define the network ports you will expose for external access like so:

```
EXPOSE 80
```

This will expos the port 80 of the container to docker.

Now you can tell docker to NAT and Forward this port to an free port of your docker host to access it. Like so:

```
docker run -p 80:80 ...
```

this will tell docker to map the host port 80 to the container port 80.

Please note that it is basically

```
host-port:container-port
```

After this you can open a browser, enter the IP of your Docker host (Ubuntu server) with port 80 and voila you are on your container ;)

Comment: this did not work for me. For some reason, I keep getting a "Unable to connect" error. I use 8888:80 for the docker run. I then use django.dev:8888 on my mac os x browser. And I have also pointed django.dev to 192.168.33.99 inside my mac os x.

I also tried boot2docker instead and I get a different set of issues. Was not able to build which was far worse.

Comment: nvm. I realized that I needed to add one more line inside my Dockerfile to ensure that my config file gets copied into the sites-enabled. My boo.